# Self join in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Why if I change condition on e1.employee_id = e2.manager_id I don't have good result.  Someone can explain to me why the order in the condition should be exactly like in the picture

[image]

Comment: The order should make no difference. Please update your question with results you get with both versions of the SQL. Also, add all information to your question as editable text, please don’t link to images

Comment: PL/SQL is the programming language. This is SQL, the query language.

Comment: Hi,  do you mean Order of the output, if yes then you need to specify the order by using the ORDER by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You just *think* the result is different; well, it is - kind of - because columns represent the same thing, but in a different order.

I don't have your tables so I'll use Scott's `EMP` table. Basically, this self-join displays employees and their managers.

Here are 2 queries with

- different joins (just as you stated)
- They also differ in `order by` clauses because I'm sorting both results by managers' names
- columns' aliases have to be fixed as well because they depend on what value they represent

---

```
select e1.ename emp_name, e2.ename mgr_name
from emp e1 join emp e2 on e1.mgr = e2.empno
order by e2.ename;

select e1.ename mgr_name, e2.ename emp_name
from emp e1 join emp e2 on e1.empno = e2.mgr
order by e1.ename;
```

This is the result (intentionally a screenshot so that you'd see that there's, actually, no difference) - only columns have changed their places.

[image]